# nodejs ssh + file copy from remote location

Tags: node.js, ssh, file-io

I am using "simple-ssh" node module that executes remote shell script and creates log file in remote system. My requirement is to email this remote file to some email address.

Step#1 : execute remote shell script that will generate log file
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');

```
var ssh = new SSH({
     host: 'remotehost',
     user: 'username',
     pass: 'password'
});

ssh.exec('someshellscript.sh ', {
    out: function(stdout) {
         console.log(stdout);
    }
}).start();
```

Step#2 : Use ssh2 to copy file from remote system to local

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;
var connSettings = {
    host: 'remotehost',
    port: 22, 
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
};

var conn = new Client();
conn.on('ready', function() {
conn.sftp(function(err, sftp) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var moveFrom = "/remote/file/path/file.txt";
    var moveTo = "/local/file/path/file.txt";

    sftp.fastGet(moveFrom, moveTo , {}, function(downloadError){
        if(downloadError) throw downloadError;

        console.log("Succesfully uploaded");
    });
});
}).connect(connSettings);
```

Is there any better way that to avoid copying of file in local system before sending email?  Can filestream API do this ?